# Error on running Scriptcs with Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, scriptcs

I have installed Scriptcs to Sublime Text 3.
I get this error when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> and build my aspx page.

> 'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I'm trying to run my aspx page on Sublime.
How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you include in your question the result of doing `where scriptcs` in a command prompt and the diagnostic output from the output panel that comes along with the error you mention above?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `scriptcs` to you `PATH` environmental variable, otherwise the system cannot find the executable.

The process is described in the [ScriptCS documentation](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2013/05/08/getting-started-with-scriptcs/):

> For simplicity, we will be using the Chocolatey Nuget method of
>   installation. Copy and paste the following command into your console.
>   This will execute a PowerShell script that will download Chocolatey,
>   place it on your local drive, and configure your path. Make sure to
>   reload your session so your new path is loaded.
>
> `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin`
>
> Next execute the
>   following command in your console. This will download ScriptCS, place
>   it on your local drive, and configure your path. Make sure to reload
>   your session again so your new path is loaded.
>
> `cinst scriptcs`

If you prefer adding `scriptcs` to your `PATH` manually (or simply want to get a better general understanding of `PATH`), have a look at this [excellent answer](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351).

Comment: Thanks but I have been installed Scriptcs. I get error on running.

Comment: I know you have installed `scriptcs`, but that's not enough. The Sublime Text package has no means to know *where* `scriptcs` is installed unless you add it to your PATH environmental variable. Once it's in your PATH you can run it from anywhere.

Comment: Read the answer at the second link I've posted, it describes the purpose of PATH perfectly.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but I think I already installed correctly with command line - I used cmd.

Comment: When you open the command prompt (or PowerShell) and execute `scriptcs`, do you get the same error as from Sublime Text. If so, then `scriptcs` is not in your PATH

Comment: No no, in cmd, its properly done, I get the error on Sublime Text when I build my aspx page. While I'm using Tools - Build

Answer (score -1):

Please try installing `SublimeREPL` and then select `scriptcs` from the available options. Once selected, try building the using `ctrl+alt+B`. https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I tried to install this in View-Search Console but it wrote No updated packages